# SQLAlchemy ORM get() returns None even though the entity exists

Tags: python, mysql, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-restful

Basically I have two API endpoints, one for creating *rules* and one for assigning *queries* to these *rules*. The process of assigning a *query* to a *rule* usually follows right after a *rule* is created. For example, the API calls would look like this:

```
POST /api/rules/
PATCH /api/rules/<id>/queries/
```

The first endpoint creates a new *rule* and stores it in the DB. The method looks like this (ignore the `print` statements for now):

```
# POST /api/rules/
def post(self, data, id):
    rule = Rule(**data)

    db.session.add(rule)
    db.session.commit()

    print 'Rule: {}'.format(
        db.engine.execute(
            'select * from rule where id = ?', rule.id)
        ).first())

    return rule, 201, location('rule', id=rule.id)
```

The second endpoint is called with the ID of the created *rule*, however, for some reason the API call **sometimes but not always** ends with a 404 Not Found:

```
# PATCH /api/rules/<id>/queries/
def patch(self, data, id):
    print 'Got rule: {}'.format(
        db.engine.execute(
            'select * from rule where id = ?', id).first())
    print 'Does SQLAlchemy see this? {}'.format(
        db.session.query(Rule).get(id) is not None)

    rule = db.session.query(Rule).get_or_404(id)
    # ... the rest ...
```

I have created a simple for-loop which tries to create 10 rules and assign 10 queries to them. Sometimes the second API call (assignment of a *query*) returns 404 status. This problem seems to occur only in production (possibly due to the higher load). When `time.sleep(1)` is put right between the first and the second API call, the problem also disappears.

This seems to be a problem in SQLAlchemy's ORM which sometimes doesn't have the most updated state of the database (?), see the following output of the `print` statements:

```
[1/POST] : Rule: (54374L, u'WBB multiplication rule')
[1/PATCH]: Got rule: (54374L, u'WBB multiplication rule')
[1/PATCH]: Does SQLAlchemy see this? True
[2/POST] : Rule: (54375L, u'WBB multiplication rule')
[2/PATCH]: Got rule: (54375L, u'WBB multiplication rule')
[2/PATCH]: Does SQLAlchemy see this? False
[3/POST] : Rule: (54376L, u'WBB multiplication rule')
[3/PATCH]: Got rule: (54376L, u'WBB multiplication rule')
[3/PATCH]: Does SQLAlchemy see this? True
```

### Additional Info

The server is running on CentOS 7 with Maria DB 10.0.21. Here is a list of some relevant Python packages:

- SQLAlchemy==1.0.6
- MySQL-python==1.2.5
- Flask==0.10.1
- Flask-RESTful==0.3.5

Note that I'm not using Flask-SQLAlchemy, although the `db.session` contains a scoped session object and I've implemented my own `first_or_404` and `get_or_404` methods.

The engine is created with the following configuration:

```
engine = create_engine(
    'mysql://{username}:{password}@{host}/{database}?charset=utf8'.format(
        **self.config),
    pool_size=50,
    pool_recycle=3600,
)
```

### With echo='debug'

The first request that creates a rule:

```
[2016-04-18 20:51:25,665: INFO/green1c0ea50 > green4196370] INSERT INTO rule (name, project_id, project_element_id, type, priority, applies, deletable) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
[2016-04-18 20:51:25,667: INFO/green1c0ea50 > green4196370] (u'WBB multiplication rule', 7013L, u'50745006', u'calc', 255, 1, 1)
[2016-04-18 20:51:25,669: INFO/green1c0ea50 > green4196370] INSERT INTO rule_calc (id, expression) VALUES (%s, %s)
[2016-04-18 20:51:25,670: INFO/green1c0ea50 > green4196370] (54625L, u'%MAX_CPC_SEARCH%*2')
[2016-04-18 20:51:25,673: INFO/green1c0ea50 > green4196370] COMMIT
[2016-04-18 20:51:25,678: INFO/green1c0ea50 > green4196370] BEGIN (implicit)
[2016-04-18 20:51:25,680: INFO/green1c0ea50 > green4196370] SELECT rule.id AS rule_id, rule.name AS rule_name, rule.project_id AS rule_project_id, rule.project_element_id AS rule_project_element_id, rule.type AS rule_type, rule.priority AS rule_priority, rule.applies AS rule_applies, rule.deletable AS rule_deletable 
FROM rule 
WHERE rule.id = %s
[2016-04-18 20:51:25,681: INFO/green1c0ea50 > green4196370] (54625L,)
[2016-04-18 20:51:25,682: INFO/MainProcess]
```

The second request that tries to fetch the rule **when it fails with 404**:

```
[2016-04-18 20:51:25,832: INFO/green1c0fa50 > green31f1e10] SELECT rule.id AS rule_id, rule.name AS rule_name, rule.project_id AS rule_project_id, rule.project_element_id AS rule_project_element_id, rule.type AS rule_type, rule.priority AS rule_priority, rule.applies AS rule_applies, rule.deletable AS rule_deletable 
FROM rule 
WHERE rule.id = %s
[2016-04-18 20:51:25,832: INFO/green1c0fa50 > green31f1e10] (u'54625',)
```

Comment: database backend needed, sqlalchemy version needed.  is replication involved?    Galera?  Oracle? (in which case see https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/3491/queryfirst-sometimes-returns-none , fixed ?)

Comment: @zzzeek Sorry. I've updated the original question and added more info (including query log when `echo='debug'` is enabled in case it helps). No replication is involved.

Comment: the second one is finding no row because you are injecting a string value into get() where there should be an integer.  the string value is not matching up and no row is returned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I believe that injecting a string value into get() is not the problem (as it works when I try it in the python interpreter and also, it wouldn't explain the random behaviour since I'm always injecting a string value). I'm going to probably fix this even though get() seems to work either way. Anyway, I'll try to isolate this more and reproduce it in sqlalchemy-only dependent environment as this behaviour doesn't seem to be related with flask. If the problem persists, I'll probably create a new issue on BitBucket.

Comment: Just to make sure this isn't related to the string value I've tried casting string to int before injecting the value into get() and the problem still persists.

Comment: then the row is not there.  im not following everything you're doing here but it would likely be a race condition of some kind between the different requests.  keep in mind transactions are isolated so if request number two started a transaction before request number one's row was established, you still might not see it.  depends on isolation level.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. The requests are serial, the second one is not made until the first one is sucessful (and the first one is not running anything asynchroniously). Also, when I don't use SQLAlchemy's ORM, instead I run `engine.execute(...)`, it works as expected (the _rule_ is always found) while `session.query(...)` returns `None`; both happens in the same request. As I said, I'll try to reproduce this in SQLAlchemy-only environment. Anyway, thank you very much for your time to read this, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Same error here, no answer